# Using interpolation in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I'm converting Python code to MATLAB, which reads an image and performs linear interpolation. I don't understand this part:

```
temp = [0,0,0] // is temp a 3d matrix with zeros??
for k in range (3) :
    temp [k] = temp[k]+(x−int(x))∗(y−int(y)) ∗(im[int(y+1), int(x+1)] [k]) // im is variable for the input image. what about k??
    temp [k] = temp[k]+(1.0−(x−int(x)))∗(1.0−(y−int(y)))∗(im[int(y), int(x)][k])
new_image[j,i] = temp // why new_image has only two coordinates??
```

Would someone give me a hint about what `(im[int(y+1) , int (x+1)] [k])` and `new_image[j,i] = temp` mean?

Comment: "why new_image has only two coordinates??" It's most likely just a single pixel.

Comment: @usr2564301 the code is just like i wrote. Ans it's exaclty like this. I don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

`im[int(y+1) , int (x+1)] [k]` this code seems to get the pixel at position `y+1, x+1` and then get channel `k` so if it is an RGB image and `k =0` then it would grab the red channel. Then `new_image[l,i] = temp` simply sets the result of the interpolation to the output image as `temp` is only 1 single pixel with 3 channels.